# Meaning of notation $f(\epsilon) = \mathrm{ord}(1)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$?

Tags: notation, asymptotics, definition

What is the meaning of 
$$ f(\epsilon) = \mathrm{ord}(1) $$ as $\epsilon \to 0$? I have struggled to find the definition of this term online or in any notes I have access to.

Comment: Is $ord(1)$ just a function? Then this would mean that f just converges to ord(1) when e approaches 0.

Comment: You should give some context.  What is f?  What book/paper is this from?  My first thought is that it means something like $f$ behaves like an order-1 polynomial close to zero, i.e. $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}f(\epsilon)/\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @BenW thank you I think that is right!